# Evitar que notificación se oculte automáticamente, ocultar únicamente con interacción del usuario

Tags: java, android, kotlin

El siguiente código funciona para mostrar notificaciones:

```
    public static void showAlarmNotification(Context context, Class<?> cls, String title, String content, int idNotification){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, cls);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(cls);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(idNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID).setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

    Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_ALARM, context.getString(R.string.alarms), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.setSound(null,null);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[] {1000, 1000, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(idNotification, notification);
}
```

Sin embargo es para una función de alarma por lo que necesito que la notificación NO se oculte como sucede normalmente (se muestra y a los 3 segundos se desliza hacía arriba automáticamente), Lo que yo necesito es que se oculte únicamente cuando el usuario la deslice hacía arriba, he investigado mucho pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, se que es posible porque la alarma de mi Samsung tiene ese comportamiento y he visto otras apps hacerlo, aquí un ejemplo:

[Ejemplo en Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65sUPQzp-oY)

Espero que me puedan dar una idea, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambiar `setContentIntent` por `setFullScreenIntent` hará el trabajo